# element.find_element searches in driver, not element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with my Selenium script. I get a list, loop through it and try to find a div in each of the elements. However, the script seems to item.find_element in driver, not the item for some reason. Anyone any idea why? It just prints all divs in all the document.

**Python:**

```
try:
    tradeables=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//cw-item"))
    )
    for item in tradeables:
        print(item.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Code to parse:**

```
<cw-item _ngcontent-rud-c407="" _nghost-rud-c381="" class="ng-tns-c381-26 hide-image-bg-icon ng-star-inserted selectable">
<!---->
<!---->
<div _ngcontent-rud-c381="" class="select-ripple-wrapper ng-tns-c381-26 ng-star-inserted">
</div>
<div _ngcontent-rud-c381="" class="left ng-tns-c381-26 ng-star-inserted">
</div>
<!---->
<!---->
<!---->
</cw-item>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you're trying to parse and what data exactly you expect to be parsed, please?

Comment: @AntonPetrov Its in the edit, sorry for not providing. Basicly there is like 5 of the codes provided, and id like to take each one and access the divs within seperately as i showed in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below to get only child elements

```
try:
    tradeables=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//cw-item"))
    )
    for item in tradeables:
        print(item.find_elements(By.XPATH, "./div"))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```